# Проблема с регулярным выражением Yii2

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, yii2

Использую фреймворк Yii2. в urlmanager стоит вот такое правило
`'<city:\D+>/arenda/<cat1:\D+\S+>' => 'arenda/default/index',`

Как мне добавить исключение символа "-"?

Answer (score 1):

если я вас правильно понял то так:

```
'<city:\D+>/arenda/<cat1:[\w-]+>' => 'arenda/default/index', http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.